# "dotnet restore" fails with "Unable to locate Dependency NETStandard.Library" message

Tags: .net, coreclr

I've installed latest .NET Core on Mac OS X, and followed the tutorial on

```
https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/
```

First I created a sample project with 'dotnet new', then ran the command 'dotnet restore'. It failed with following messages:

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CoreClr-x64-1.0.0-rc1-16231

  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Restoring packages for /Users/cookie/Documents/Github/t/project.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/netstandard.library/index.json
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/netstandard.library/index.json 2388ms
Unable to locate Dependency NETStandard.Library >= 1.0.0-rc2-23616
Writing lock file /Users/cookie/Documents/Github/t/project.lock.json
Restore complete, 2759ms elapsed

Errors in /Users/cookie/Documents/Github/t/project.json
    Unable to locate Dependency NETStandard.Library >= 1.0.0-rc2-23616

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
```

I got 404 error on

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/netstandard.library/index.json
```

I tried the same approach on Windows, which also fails. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit : It seems it was a bug, which was discussed in  https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/535 . Latest installation packages now generates NuGet.config, and successfully retrieves NETStandard.Library from myget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NETStandard.Library` hasn't been yet released on NuGet. Add

```
<add key="DotNet-Core" value="https://myget.org/f/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
```

to your `NuGet.config` file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I couldn't locate nuget.config file, so I thought that there was a problem in latest .NET Core package. (I found that "dotnet new" generates Program.cs / .json only.) So I tried downloading and installing .NET Core installer again, and this time "dotnet  new" generates NuGet.config successfully. (it has link to myget in "dotnet-core" key in it).

Answer (score 1):

To add a little more explicit information to Victor's answer in case your `nuget.config` file looks like mine.  There are multiple sections to the file, and the key needs to be added to `<packageSources>` within `<configuration>` so that your file ends up looking something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
       <packageSources>
         <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
         <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
         <add key="DotNet-Core" value="https://myget.org/f/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
      </packageSources>
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail information! As I wrote in Victor's answer, I think there was a problem in .NET Core installer package. "dotnet new" generated only two files (Program.cs/json) and NuGet.config was not generated. I download and installed package again, and this time it creates  nuget.config just as you described. Thanks!